# How does Cura slice the bottom layers in vase (spiralize) mode?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, vase-mode

Cura 4.x doesn't seem to honor normal bottom/skin settings when slicing in vase (spiralize) mode, and does something weird where it alternates at each layer between filling the skin region with lines (like a normal bottom layer) and doing concentric fill for some number of loops before switching to lines. The [Cura 5.x beta (Arachne)](https://ultimaker.com/learn/get-an-engine-boost-with-ultimaker-cura-and-arachne-beta) seems to use just concentric fill. Is the behavior documented anywhere, and is there any way to tune or override it? I'm hitting problems with the concentric part not being sufficiently water-tight (while normal lines fill in alternating directions *is* always water-tight for me).

I build CuraEngine myself from source, so answers citing where this logic lives in the source would be acceptable for me (so I could just change it there) if there's no better configurability.